# Hadoop mapper reading from 2 different source input files

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I have tool which chains a lot of Mappers & Reducers, and at some point I need merge results from previous map-reduce steps, for example as input I have two files with data:

```
/input/a.txt
apple,10
orange,20

*/input/b.txt*
apple;5
orange;40
```

result should be c.txt, where **c.value = a.value * b.value**

```
/output/c.txt
apple,50   // 10 * 5
orange,800 // 40 * 20
```

How it could be done? I've resolved this with introducing simple Key => MyMapWritable (type=1,2, value), and merging (actually, multiplying) data in reducers. It works, but:

1. have feeling that it could be done easier (smells not good)
2. is it possible somehow to know inside Mapper which exactly file was used as record provider (a.txt or b.txt). For now, I just used different separators: coma & semicolon :(

Answer (score 3):

Assuming they have been partitioned and sorted in the same way, then you can use the [CompositeInputFormat](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/r1.0.3/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/join/CompositeInputFormat.html) to perform a map-side-join. There's an article on using it [here](http://www.congiu.com/joins-in-hadoop-using-compositeinputformat/). I don't think it's been ported to the new mapreduce api though.

Secondly, you can get the input file in the mapper by calling `context.getInputSplit()`, this will return the InputSplit, which if you're using `TextInputFormat`, you can cast to a `FileInputSplit` and then call `getPath()` to get the file name. I don't think you can use this method with CompositeInputFormat though as you won't know where the Writables in the TupleWritable have come from.

Answer (score 1):

```
String fileName = ((FileSplit) context.getInputSplit()).getPath()
                .toString();

if (fileName.contains("file_1")) {
   //TODO for file 1
} else {
   //TODO for file 2
}
```